# Shooting and Transferring files simultaneously

Tags: camera, sony, sony-camera-api

Is it possible to SHOOT and TRANFER FILES SIMULTANEOUSLY with an Action Cam?

With the SDK API, I'd like to develop a PC software that it can do this:

1. Camera is shooting
2. Stop shooting
3. Change camera function in "Content Transfer"
4. Transfer the movie file just recorded on wifi connection
5. Change camera function in "Remote Shooting" (while file is
       transferring!!!)
6. Start shooting (movie on another file)

Is it possibile? Or how could I do to stop as little as possible shooting?

Thank'you very much

roberto

Comment: always try to add some code or reference to your questions to show that you try to find the answer on your own before ask for help, it will avoid other users to vote you down and will make they see that you are really serious about find the answer for your question. Good luck with your quest!

Comment: Thanks @IcaroNZ! But now I'm **designing** the system, I have not written the code. I have to figure out if it is technically possible to transfer files and record simultaneously. I have not even chosen the model of action cam. In fact I think only a technical sony or an expert can answer. I hope...

Answer (score 0):

I am struggling with the same problem but unfortunately you can't continue downloading the file if you set back the camera to `REMOTE_SHOOTING`